# How to get project ID using Go SDK for Google cloud platform?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to fetch project-id in Go through the service account I am using in my system so that whenever that code runs on a compute instance in GCP, it should retrieve the project-id where the compute instance lies. Also if I run the code from my local machine, it should get the project-id same as "gcloud info" command gets from command line.

Does anyone have any idea which API to use in Go?

Comment: Your posted code has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: @mbuechmann Edited the question to remove confusion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured out the correct API.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    credentials, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx,compute.ComputeScope)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf(credentials.ProjectID)
}
```

Comment: Using `error` as a variable name is not a great idea - there's a _built-in_ interface with this name

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on my local instance (it returns without error but ProjectID is blank).

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the project ID of the Compute Engine instance by using the Google Cloud API [1] with a GET **request to** **“http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id”** with the **header “Metadata-Flavor: Google”** in order to be allowed.

It can be tested in the Cloud Shell or a secure shell (SSH) terminal by using:

> curl
>   "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id"
>   -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"

[1] : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#default

Comment: This solution will only work on google cloud instances which makes it difficult to during development to run on local machine

Comment: You can't fetch metadata of a compute instance if you are running it on local and not in a compute instance, but during development you might run it in a free instance. Look here: https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits